# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I tried to execute this Selenium Script,

```
public class FirePath_Ex {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();
        d.get("https://facebook.com");
        d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("dhhfdssd");
        d.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("sjfsdfj");
    }
}
```

it shows the error below after closing FireFox,

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
>       Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
>       System info: host: 'Admin-PC', ip: '192.168.0.101', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.7.0-ea'
>       Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:445)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:358)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
>         at FirePath_Ex.main(FirePath_Ex.java:13)
>       Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7055 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What is your firefox browser version?

Comment: It seems there's a compatability issue. try with selenium 2.47.1 and ff 39.x version

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this below code and replace the path of firefox exe with your absolute path:-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\firefox.exe");
```

So your code should be like:-

public class FirePath_Ex {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\firefox.exe");
    WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();
    d.get("https://facebook.com");
    d.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("dhhfdssd");
    d.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("sjfsdfj");
}
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy for quite a bit.

For me, simply re-instantiating it solved the problem some of the time. (like below). However, 95% of the time it's because my selenium version is not compatible with the firefox version. The documentation for supported version is not easy to parse, nor does it contain an exhaustive list. Sometimes it takes some trail and error.

```
public FirefoxWebPageReader firefoxWebPageReader() {
    return forceInit(3);
}

private FirefoxWebPageReader forceInit(final int tries) {
    if (tries == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can not initialize Firefox reader");
    }
    try {
        final String binaryPath = environment.getProperty("crawler.firefox.path");
        return new FirefoxWebPageReader(binaryPath);

    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occurred when building FirefoxWebPageReader, tries left: " + (tries - 1), e);
        return forceInit(tries - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The probable reason may be the incompatibility between the browser and the chromedriver, so installing the updated chromedriver or updating chrome might help